# How I can continue a .bat file after closing the CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I use Windows' Command Prompt to encode an "Anime video" --
but it takes about 10 hours to finish!

I can't leave the laptop for 10 hours, because I use it in my work.

I want a method to close the CMD and continue it again to avoid restarting the batch file from the beginning.

Is there a method like that?

Comment: Really you are asking about **resuming** a process, not realling continuing it once the CMD is closed.  In any case, if you want help, you should post the command you use to start the process - since what you are asking is more a feature of your program than CMD's status.  Please **update your post** with that and do not *add a comment*.

Comment: No, the "encoder x264" use CMD
and I wanna CMD To resume
because x264 use CMD Not a GUI

Comment: @user242616: That would still be a feature of the program. Which program are you using? (And what do you mean by “left the laptop for 10 hours”? You can’t leave it on, or you can’t leave the program using up resources?)

Comment: It is x264
I Put this encoder and the video in one folder
and create a .bat file to encode it

(I can't leave The Laptop on -___-)

Comment: “x264” is the name of your program? Great. Could you please show the `.bat` file you created?

Comment: x264-10bit.exe --preset slower --level 4 --ref 9 --deblock=1:-1:1 --subme=10 --psy-rd=0.90:0.04 --threads=15 --lookahead-threads=2 --bframes=10 --crf=17.0 --qcomp=0.68 --aq-mode=2 --output "Script.h264" "Script.avs"

Comment: To quote @nerdwaller, “Please update your post with that and do not add a comment.”

Comment: @user242616 [click here](http://superuser.com/posts/626834/edit) to edit your post.

Comment: Rather than stop the command or run the laptop off can you leave the command running then hibernate the machine? That way it will continue after you resume the machine...

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to create a virtual machine with MS Virtual PC or Oracle's VirtualBox.  Install the encoding program on the virtual machine.  Then you could run the program in the virtual machine and suspend and resume the entire virtual machine as necessary.  This would accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: Great idea, though it assumes one is allowed to install software on a work laptop. (Which generally should not be the case).

Answer (score 1):

Your actual question seems to be: "Can I resume a program -In this case started from cmd.exe- after I shut down windows".

The answer is generally: No.

What you can do is:

1. Run it on another computer. E.g. a non-work related one (keep work and private stuff seperarte!)
2. Leave the work laptop on during an evening and night.
3. Find a faster way to do this. In your command I notice a `--threads=15`. Is that really the fastest option? Do you have 15+ CPU cores? (Or 8 cores with HT?)

If you need to convert this anime for work then ask your admin for an account on a server.

Comment: I wish watching anime was part of my job...